# Getting MySQL query result without error messages (suppress error messages)

Tags: mysql

I need to suppress all error messages that the `mysql` command prints to stdout. I saw many other similar questions but all answers suggest workarounds to avoid these messages (check database/table/column exists before executing query). But I need the `mysql` command to return a failure exit code on error and don't print anything to output except the data explicitly requested in a query in a successful run. The `-s` key doesn't help in hiding error messages.

My task is to execute a MySQL query in a script and get either the requested data (printed with the `-s` key) or a non-zero exit code. I don't want to check each and every table/column/etc existence before executing a target query. How can I achieve this?

UPD: I tried this but it didn't help:

```
mysql ... db -s -N -e "SELECT config_id FROM core_config_data LIMIT 1;" 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

To sum it up:

You want the `mysql` command to:

- not print any error
- exit with a non-success code when a query fails

Then I've got good news for you! The output of errors will always be on `stderr`. Therefore you can just redirect the output to null or whatever you like.

```
root@icarus ~/so # mariadb -Dmaio290sql1 -e 'SELECT * FROM wp_users' -s 2> bla.txt
[actual content]
root@icarus ~/so # echo $?
0
root@icarus ~/so # mariadb -Dmaio290sql1 -e 'SELECT * FROM nope' -s 2> bla.txt
root@icarus ~/so # echo $?
1
```

The last query is throwing an error and therefore the exit code is not 0.
This was tested on MariaDB though: `10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 Debian 10`.

Comment: Could you confirm this with the `mysql` executable, not `mariadb`?